# onClick events not rendering in NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, onclick, portal

I have a contact button in my header I want it to render a modal when clicked. I create state variables for the click event and imported a modal component into my header file. I've tried making a handleClick function for the onClick event as well as don't it without this as you will see. I can't quite see why I can't get it working. I've googled the sh*t out of this with nothing seems to help.

header file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Link as LinkScroll } from "react-scroll";
import ButtonOutline from "../misc/ButtonOutline";
import Modal from "../Modal";

const Header = () => {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState(null);
  const [scrollActive, setScrollActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      setScrollActive(window.scrollY > 20);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <header
        className={
          "fixed top-0 w-full  z-30 bg-white-500 transition-all " +
          (scrollActive ? " shadow-md pt-0" : " pt-4")
        }
      >
        <nav className="max-w-screen-xl px-6 sm:px-8 lg:px-16 mx-auto grid grid-flow-col py-3 sm:py-4">
          <div className="col-start-1 col-end-2 flex items-center">
            <h1 className="h-8 w-auto text-2xl font-Amatic text-black-500 hover:text-green-500 cursor-pointer">
              Soul Amiga
            </h1>
          </div>
          <ul className="hidden lg:flex col-start-4 col-end-8 text-black-500 items-center">
            <LinkScroll
              activeClass="active"
              to="home"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              onSetActive={() => {
                setActiveLink("home");
              }}
              className={
                "px-4 py-2 mx-2 cursor-pointer animation-hover inline-block relative" +
                (activeLink === "home"
                  ? " text-green-500 animation-active "
                  : " text-black-500 hover:text-green-500 ")
              }
            >
              Home
            </LinkScroll>
            <LinkScroll
              activeClass="active"
              to="about"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              onSetActive={() => {
                setActiveLink("about");
              }}
              className={
                "px-4 py-2 mx-2 cursor-pointer animation-hover inline-block relative" +
                (activeLink === "about"
                  ? " text-green-500 animation-active "
                  : " text-black-500 hover:text-green-500 ")
              }
            >
              About
            </LinkScroll>
            <LinkScroll
              activeClass="active"
              to="mywork"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              onSetActive={() => {
                setActiveLink("mywork");
              }}
              className={
                "px-4 py-2 mx-2 cursor-pointer animation-hover inline-block relative" +
                (activeLink === "mywork"
                  ? " text-green-500 animation-active "
                  : " text-black-500 hover:text-green-500 ")
              }
            >
              My Work
            </LinkScroll>
            <LinkScroll
              activeClass="active"
              to="blog"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              onSetActive={() => {
                setActiveLink("blog");
              }}
              className={
                "px-4 py-2 mx-2 cursor-pointer animation-hover inline-block relative" +
                (activeLink === "blog"
                  ? " text-green-500 animation-active "
                  : " text-black-500 hover:text-green-500 ")
              }
            >
              Blog
            </LinkScroll>
          </ul>
          <div className="col-start-10 col-end-12 font-medium flex justify-end items-center">
            <ButtonOutline
              onClick={() => {
                setModalOpen(true);
              }}
            >
              Contact
            </ButtonOutline>
            <Modal open={modalOpen} />
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      {/* Mobile Navigation */}

      <nav className="fixed lg:hidden bottom-0 left-0 right-0 z-20 px-4 sm:px-8 shadow-t ">
        <div className="bg-white-500 sm:px-3">
          <ul className="flex w-full justify-between items-center text-black-500">
            <LinkScroll
              activeClass="active"
              to="home"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              onSetActive={() => {
                setActiveLink("home");
              }}
              className={
                "mx-1 sm:mx-2 px-3 sm:px-4 py-2 flex flex-col items-center text-xs border-t-2 transition-all " +
                (activeLink === "home"
                  ? "  border-green-500 text-green-500"
                  : " border-transparent")
              }
            >
              <svg
                className="w-6 h-6"
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth={2}
                  d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
                />
              </svg>
              Home
            </LinkScroll>
            <LinkScroll
              activeClass="active"
              to="about"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              onSetActive={() => {
                setActiveLink("about");
              }}
              className={
                "mx-1 sm:mx-2 px-3 sm:px-4 py-2 flex flex-col items-center text-xs border-t-2 transition-all " +
                (activeLink === "about"
                  ? "  border-green-500 text-green-500"
                  : " border-transparent ")
              }
            >
              <svg
                className="w-6 h-6"
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth={2}
                  d="M21 12a9 9 0 01-9 9m9-9a9 9 0 00-9-9m9 9H3m9 9a9 9 0 01-9-9m9 9c1.657 0 3-4.03 3-9s-1.343-9-3-9m0 18c-1.657 0-3-4.03-3-9s1.343-9 3-9m-9 9a9 9 0 019-9"
                />
              </svg>
              About
            </LinkScroll>
            <LinkScroll
              activeClass="active"
              to="mywork"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              onSetActive={() => {
                setActiveLink("mywork");
              }}
              className={
                "mx-1 sm:mx-2 px-3 sm:px-4 py-2 flex flex-col items-center text-xs border-t-2 transition-all " +
                (activeLink === "mywork"
                  ? "  border-green-500 text-green-500"
                  : " border-transparent ")
              }
            >
              <svg
                className="w-6 h-6"
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth={2}
                  d="M12 8c-1.657 0-3 .895-3 2s1.343 2 3 2 3 .895 3 2-1.343 2-3 2m0-8c1.11 0 2.08.402 2.599 1M12 8V7m0 1v8m0 0v1m0-1c-1.11 0-2.08-.402-2.599-1M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
                />
              </svg>
              My Work
            </LinkScroll>
            <LinkScroll
              activeClass="active"
              to="blog"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              duration={1000}
              onSetActive={() => {
                setActiveLink("blog");
              }}
              className={
                "mx-1 sm:mx-2 px-3 sm:px-4 py-2 flex flex-col items-center text-xs border-t-2 transition-all " +
                (activeLink === "blog"
                  ? "  border-green-500 text-green-500"
                  : " border-transparent ")
              }
            >
              <svg
                className="w-6 h-6"
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth={2}
                  d="M8 12h.01M12 12h.01M16 12h.01M21 12c0 4.418-4.03 8-9 8a9.863 9.863 0 01-4.255-.949L3 20l1.395-3.72C3.512 15.042 3 13.574 3 12c0-4.418 4.03-8 9-8s9 3.582 9 8z"
                />
              </svg>
              Blog
            </LinkScroll>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      {/* End Mobile Navigation */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

modal file:

```
   import React from "react";

import ButtonPrimary from "./misc/ButtonPrimary";

function Modal({ open }) {
  if (!open) return null;
  return (
    <div className="modalBackground">
      <div className="modalContainer">
        <button> X </button>
        <div className="title">
          <h1>Soul Amiga</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="body">
          <p>Name</p>
          <p>Email</p>
          <textarea />
        </div>
        <div className="footer">
          <ButtonPrimary text="Send" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Modal;
```

Comment: can you create a codesandbox to review it?

Comment: It look like there is no mistake for the `modalOpen` logic, but the error could be somewhere else. What is in `ButtonOutline`, is it from a UI library?

Comment: its reusable button component

Comment: are you sure that the `ButtonOutline` handles `onClick` correctly?

Comment: In the above example, I handled the onClick inside the imported ButtonOutline component that gets rendered from the Header file. Before submitting this question  I tried handling the onClick inside the ButtonOutline component file however that also didn't work for me.  Is that what you are suggesting I try?